# swiftmailer yii2 ошибка при попытке отправить почту

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Что делаю не так?
Копирую с mailtrap.io конфигурацию для yii

```php
    'components' => [
        .....
        'mail' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
                'username' => 'uname',
                'password' => 'upass',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

далее в контролере

```
$this->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom('from@yiisoft.local')
            ->setTo('myemail@mail.ru')
            ->setSubject('Email sent from Yii2-Swiftmailer')
            ->send();
```

и при попытке выполнить получаю

```
Swift_TransportException

Expected response code 220 but got an empty response
```

Не могу понять в чем причина.

PS: Проект развернут локально.

PSPS: На всякий случай добавлю сюда composer.json, т.к. использую только ядро yii. Может что доустановить нужно?

```
{
    "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2": "^2.0",
        "vkcom/vk-php-sdk": "5.95.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.28"
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы нормальные настройки пробовали подставить? В данном случае smtp сервер вернул пустой ответ, видимо из-за некорректных данных(host, username, password)

Comment: @Romka Ниже описал проблему

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема из за некорректной инъекции в конструктор контроллера, т.е. делал так:

```php
__construct(..., Mailer $mailer, ..., ...)
```

При этом его конфиги прописывал в файле config/web.php в секции components.
Сделал так:

```php
Yii::$app->mailer->compose(...
```

и все заработало